# Wordpress rewrite with custom folder structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have this setup on my Wordpress installation:

```
public_html/
---------- /index.php
---------- /app/
---------- /wp/
---------- /.htaccess
```

`wp` is the mail Wordpress and the `app` is the wp-content folder renamed.

The index.php is now:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

and I have add these lines on `/wp/wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',  dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../app' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL',  'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/app' );
```

Now the admin is ok, but when I navigate on front, it always redirect to the main domain.

if I point to `http://mydomani.com/test-page` redirect to `http://mydomani.com`

also if I point to `http://mydomani.com/index.php` redirect to `http://mydomani.com`

Where I can look for correct this?

Comment: Not editing the htaccess file to do this?

Comment: No, htaccess is the original one